# Google Classroom - Modify Attachments method

Tags: json, rest, service, patch, google-classroom

I'm trying to use Google Classroom API - mainly the Student Submission - Modify Attachments method (https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/modifyAttachments) to implement a student posting a link to an assignment - the link in question is very public and accessible (a page on wikipedia, for instance).

I've managed to list the student's courses, coursework and submissions using the Rest services. However, I'm finding it very difficult to make the Modify Attachments method work. As of now, I'm sending the following data in the request body:

```
{
  "addAttachments": [
    {
      "link": {
        "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And the result is an error 400 - invalid argument:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Strangely enough, even using Google's own tools (C# library, JS library, Test on Developer Console page) I'm getting the same error (I used the developer console to create the work item as a teacher and then, in a separate browser instance, used the student account to make the call - to avoid permission issues - the know error 403).

Am I missing something in the body of my request? Is it a request that can only be performed by a teacher?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I also tried using the method above with a teacher authentication - to no avail - same results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to say that I was using the wrong question type - I was trying to post an attachment to a multiple answer question and thus the Google API prevented my from doing this - I only wish error messages were a little better